# syntax for passing params and depends to custom method in jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add a depends clause to a custom validation routine in jquery validate. What's the syntax to pass the parameter object? So it's supposed to check the archive Date is after the value in publishDate, but only if the checkbox isn't checked. Note that the method works fine when there's no depends and I just add `afterDate: '#publishDate'`. I'm just trying to work out how to pass the params object to the function...

```
archiveDate.rules("add",{
        afterDate: {
            params: ["#publishDate"],
            depends: '#publishNow:unchecked'
        },
        messages: {
          afterDate: 'Archive date should be after publish date'
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: You should have included enough code for a working example that includes your call to `.validate()` and the relevant HTML markup.  Otherwise, we have to assume you've made zero syntax errors outside of the ones you've shown.

Comment: I mentioned the code works fine without the depends call. What I was looking for was just how to pass the "param" which the answer you posted addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is the same as if you were using it within the `.validate()` method.

- `depends` logic needs to be wrapped in a function that returns `true` or `false`.
- It's spelled `param`, not `params`.

[Refer to the documentation.](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules)

Assuming that `archiveDate` represents a valid jQuery selector of the element targeted for validation, and `afterDate` represents the custom method name...

```
archiveDate.rules("add",{
    afterDate: { // <- name of custom method
        param: ["#publishDate"],
        depends: function(element) {
            return $('#publishNow').is(':unchecked');
        }
    },
    messages: {
        afterDate: 'Archive date should be after publish date'
    }
});
```

**Note**:  Since `afterDate` is a custom method, you should not need to use it in conjunction with a `depends`.  That logic could easily be built into the custom method itself.

Comment: Thanks "param" is what I was looking for. I did check the docs a few times already and couldn't find mention of the parameter name. Now that I know what I'm looking for it is there in one of the examples. Also that function is added generically, so I don't want to add form specific logic to it. It's working well now... thanks...